# Random walks with limited number of visits

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I'm interested in random walks (esp. their hitting times) such that the number of visits to each state is limited by some parameter $K$.

Is there any canonical name for such stochastic processes?
Maybe some literature or research papers?

Any info or references will be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of graph are you walking on?